# Two fix level top navbars in bootstrap

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

How can I have 2 fix top navbars with Bootstrap (latest version)?

First navbar has the first level like:

| Home | Projects | Customers | Reporting |

If a user clicks on Projects then the second menu should be visible all the time (so no dropdown).  Like this:

| Home | **Projects** | Customers | Reporting | My profile |

| **List all projects** | Create new project | Archived projects

So when user clicks on projects then the first sublevel because active but also the whole second top navbar should show the subitems for Projects.

I hope it's clear what I mean?   Is something like this possible with Bootstrap?

Answer (score 0):

Is it this you are trying to archive: [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/farnholdt/8nHAA/)

Instead of two navs, it is also possible to use nav-pils below the first nav

```
<ul class="nav nav-pills">
<li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
<li><a href="#">All projects</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Create new</a></li>
</ul>
```

See documentation for more information: [Bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/components/#nav)

Comment: Thanks for your answer.  No not really.  Those are indeed two navbars but they aren't connected.  It's not like you choose the first level on top and then the second level menu items of that parent are displayed.